# Can video files created using the LEGO Movie Maker app be accessed directly?

Tags: software

I recently created a video with my son using the LEGO Movie Maker app. I couldn't find a way to export the raw video files out of the app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I wasn't able to find a way to export the videos via the application UI, I was able to locate these at the following path on Android: `/data/data/com.lego.moviemaker.thelegomovie2/files`

On my device, there were mp4 movie files located here along with a few other files. These can be moved around like any other file, and play just fine using VLC or other media players. You likely need a rooted device to access these.